# creating packages in netbeans

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans, glassfish

I am new to NetBeans and learning how to create java EE application with it. If I create a java enterprise application and put a basic servlet in the default package, then the browser will display the servlets output, but when I put it in a java package, the glassfish displays a message in the browser stating that the request resource is not available.

I am using NetBeans IDE 8.2 and the glassfish server bundled with it.

I cannot work out the problem. Can someone help?

Comment: How are you setting mapping between URL and your servlet class? Is it in deployment description (`web.xml` file) or via annotation?

Comment: Annotation. It done via the the new servlet option